# Wordpress custom meta box save

Tags: php, wordpress, web

Okay so I have a working custom meta box in my theme that works and saves fine. I have created the second meta box and the box appears and there is no errors being displayed. But the content doesn't save. When I click update the box clears. The code is below:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'sizes_meta_box_save' );

function sizes_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE_SIZES' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE_SIZES ) return;

// if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
if( !isset( $_POST['sizes_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['sizes_meta_box_nonce'], 'sizes_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

// if our current user can't edit this post, bail
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

// Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
if( isset( $_POST['sizes_meta_description'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sizes_meta_description', wp_kses( $_POST['sizes_meta_description'], $allowed ) );
}    
}
```

The first box works like I said all I have done is renamed everything that has 'sizes' in or next to it. Pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue still persists?

I couldn't see an error in you snippet.
Have you already check that `$_POST['sizes_meta_description']` is set?